# RecursiveIteratorIterator: include directory and php files in zip

Tags: php, iterator, php-ziparchive

I have a script which ZIPS directories, but need to add *.php files also.

Issue having is error is thrown when adding something like ../index.php.

Error produced by script below is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(../index.php): failed to open dir: Not a directory' in /home/mathtest/public_html/trig/admin/save.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /home/mathtest/public_html/trig/admin/save.php(23): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('../index.php') #1 {main} thrown in /home/mathtest/public_html/trig/admin/save.php on line 23
```

My script:

```
<?php

/* CONFIG */

$pathToAssets = array("../images", "../Data", "../css", "../index.php");

$filename = "temp/backup.zip";

/* END CONFIG */


$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);


//add folder structure

foreach ($pathToAssets as $thePath) {

    // Create recursive directory iterator
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($thePath), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );


    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {

        if ($file->getFilename() != '.' && $file->getFilename() != '..') {

            // Get real path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();

            $temp = explode("/", $name);

            array_shift($temp);

            $newName = implode("/", $temp);

            // Add current file to archive
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $newName);
        }
    }
}

$zip->close();

$yourfile = $filename;

$file_name = basename($yourfile);

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($yourfile));

readfile($yourfile);

unlink('temp/backup.zip');

exit;
?>
```

I have read about RecursiveIteratorIterator at http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php and also many questions here without luck in solving.

Replacing ../index.php with just ../ works, but that includes directories that do not want placed in zip.

Any input to allow insertion of php in downloaded zip much appreciated.

Comment: A RecursiveDirectoryIterator will only take directories to scan. So, you might have to deal with files separately, or you might be able to adapt your iterator to include files too.  The first comment on https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php by Thriault deals with php files.

Comment: Thanks @jedifans. I had tried that b4 posting but not working. Could be I have not adapted to my script correctly as get no php files in zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) or [`CallbackFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.callbackfilteriterator.php). If you use the same filters in multiple places better to use [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php). For the simplicity, I use [`CallbackFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.callbackfilteriterator.php) and define the filter function that uses [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to decide whether the file will be present in the loop.

```
$path = '../test';

$directories = ['images', 'Data', 'css'];

$filter = function ($current, $key, $iterator) use ($path, $directories) {
    $path = preg_quote($path, '/');
    $directories = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $directories));

    if (preg_match('/^' . $path . '\/(' . $directories . ')/', $key)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (preg_match('/^' . $path . '.+\.php$/', $key)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};

$files = new CallbackFilterIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
            $path,
            FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
        ),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    ),
    $filter
);

foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    // Do something with files.
    var_dump($key, $file);
}
```

Take a notice of [`FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants.skip-dots) flag. It helps you to avoid code like this:

```
if ($file->getFilename() != '.' && $file->getFilename() != '..') {
    // ...
}
```

The other approach will be to use your original code to add directories only, but for files use [`ZipArchive::addPattern`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addpattern.php) method:

```
$zip->addPattern('/\.(?:php)$/', $path)
```

Be aware, that **the pattern will be matched against the file name only**.

Comment: Thank you @sevavietl. This is very good explanation and example, going to use it!